# Updating another ViewModel on PropertyChanged of another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, inotifypropertychanged

Both ViewModels know nothing about each other, but i need to send the new value that have changed in one viewmodel to a method in the other view model, what are my options?

could you please list all possibilities and what would be the best way?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19191496/643085) to a similar question.

Comment: @HighCore is an Event Aggregator the best way?

Comment: yes, if you don't want to have a reference from one ViewModel to the other.

Comment: I would recommend an Event Aggregator.  @HighCore linked to one.  There are any number of examples once you know what to search for.

Comment: Plus one for me. Event Aggregator.

Comment: @HighCore Thank you :) it worked as it should ,please feel free to write an answer, but i still wonder why you called it DumbAggregator, what could a smarter one do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19191496/643085):

If you want loosely-coupled communication you need an EventAggregator:

```
//Simplest EventAggregator
public static class DumbAggregator
{
    public static void BroadCast(string message)
    {
       if (OnMessageTransmitted != null)
           OnMessageTransmitted(message);
    }

    public static Action<string> OnMessageTransmitted;
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MySender
{
   public void SendMessage()
   {
       DumbAggregator.BroadCast("Hello There!");
   }
}

public class MySubscriber
{
   public MySubscriber()
   {
       DumbAggregator.OnMessageTransmitted += OnMessageReceived;
   }

   private void OnMessageReceived(string message)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("I Received a Message! - " + message);
   }
}
```

Notice however, that EventAggregators included in MVVM frameworks such as Prism are much more complex and include a whole lot of functionality. This is just a simple example.